# Android RadioButton not able to unset using setChecked(false) method

Tags: android, radio-button

If I set a radio button to be selected on the first time, it works fine. But if I unselect it by calling 
     ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID)).setChecked(false);
then, later even if I try to make it selected by calling setChecked(true) will not work unless the user select it from the screen.

Have any one come across this? or is it only me?

```
        if(Val != null){
        if( ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID1)).getText().toString().trim().equals(Val))
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID1)).setChecked(true);
        else if(((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID2)).getText().toString().trim().equals(Val))
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID2)).setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID1)).setChecked(false);
            ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ID2)).setChecked(false);
        }
```

If the else part is executed atleast once then everything gets mess up.
When I step thro my debugger, I can see the execution goes in the correct path and setting it to true. It is getting executed only once, I checked that. And I am not resetting it back to false in any other part of the code.

Comment: Could we see your sourcecode ?

Comment: I tried this android:saveEnabled="false", after going thro http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8ad42efded222543 , but that didnt help me. Wow atleast I am not alone...

Comment: Have the same Problem and while my layout is

Image - Text - Check
Image - Text - Check

i can not make only one RadioGroup ... i found that it is a 'bug' when i can not set the Radio with setChecked(false) what the android-developer must do unfix.

Thanks for your info, will try it ...

Comment: Your Welcome. Did that work for you?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the solution.

It is not possible to uncheck a particular radio button. You can only set the other item to true.

So to clear all the checked items, you should call the `clearcheck()` method on the RadioGroup.

So my else part is

```
        else {
            ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ID0)).clearCheck();
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! It gets really messy with radio buttons sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: Or in my case it got clearer when I took off RadioGroup and played with two RadioButtons.

Comment: This solved my issue. I was trying to recheck the already checked radio button which shwoing it as unchecked in UI.

Answer (score 2):

Take one invisible radio button and check it. All other radio buttons of group will be unchecked automatically..