# RadioButton and Switch Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a Switch and a RadioButton. I want that when I click and check the Switch the RadioButton will be unchecked and viceversa. How can I do this?

**My code is:**

```
 Switch switchButton = new Switch(this);
 RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);

 switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(switchButton.isChecked()){
                radioButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });


radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(radioButton.isChecked()){
                    switchButton.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

My code doesn't work as I aspected, can you help me please, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `setOnClickListener()` but needs to use `setnCheckedChangeListener()`

See the below code

```
Switch switchButton = new Switch(this);
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);

switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                radioButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                switchButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `OnCheckedChangeListener()` on the `switchButton`
to listen for state changes in the `Switch`

```
 switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                switchButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

use the same listener on your `RadioButton`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the buttons in your view? If you do, you need to use the [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findviewbyid) function to bind to that view in order to change the buttons. If you just programmatically create a button it wont appear on the view.

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.your_radio_bt_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036050/7252861), a single radio button cannot be cleared. Instead you need to clear the whole radio group.

So instead of

```
radioButton.setChecked(false);
```

you need to use

```
((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_RADIO_GROUP)).clearCheck();
```

Also, you haven't specified in your question what exactly isn't working as expected.
If this doesn't solve your problem, please comment with what exactly are you getting when you try to trigger the switch or the radio button.

EDIT: Also, you should use `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` instead of `setOnClickListener()`

Comment: I don't use a RadioGroup , I use a RecyclerView that contains RadioButton , in the adapter I save in an instance variable  the RadioButton that is checked and when I check another RadioButton the previous RadioButton saved will be unchecked and the new will take its place....

Comment: I want that when I check the Switch button the RadioButton will be unchecked and viceversa

Comment: @vaniokmd Do try using the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` as suggested by other answers.